# How to change the height of the KeyPreview

Tags: android

I am making a soft keyboard and I want to change the key preview height of the soft keyboard.

```
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:gb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="200dp"
   android:background="@drawable/shape_key_preview_bkgnd" />
```

The height of the key preview is not changing at all . How can i change the height of the key Preview

Comment: you can change the key preview width, but not height.

Answer (score 2):

You should add following code to your keyboard view layout xml file.

```
android:keyPreviewHeight="200dp"
```